# how to avoid duplicating while looping with for loop?

Tags: php

I am making a sql request to get all students of a teacher from a database
my problem is that when I am fetching these data I get displayed the name
of the teacher with every single student , 
I am expecting to have something displayed like this :

teach1
student1
student2
student3

but instead i get:

teach1
student1 teach1
student2 teach1
student3 teach1

could you please help to solve this issue ,
this is my sql request :

```
SELECT a.name, b.nameTeacher 
FROM table1 b JOIN
     table2 a
     ON a.id_teacher = b.id ;
```

and this is how I am looping my data with for loop

```
foreach($this->TeacherStudents as $key => $value){


  echo  $value['nameTeacher'];
  echo  '<a href="'.$url.'"> '.$value['name'].'</a>  <span class="badge">';


    }
```

Comment: Can you try Group By clause in your query so that you will have unique record in loop

Comment: @AyazShah that will fetch only the last record

Comment: @Cid true this will display one record per loop

Comment: and I can't put staticly echo $this->TeacherStudents[0] .. cause I don't know  how much teachers are there , needs to be looped

Comment: Yep, I'm wrong, there's no where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the sql query so that it returns the teachers in order:

```
SELECT a.name, b.nameTeacher 
FROM table1 b JOIN
     table2 a
 ON a.id_teacher = b.id order by b.id;
```

Then change the for loop so that it prints out the teachers name only once:

```
$lastTeacher = null;
foreach($this->TeacherStudents as $key => $value){
    if($lastTeacher != $value['nameTeacher']) {
       echo  $value['nameTeacher'];
       echo '<br>';
       $lastTeacher = $value['nameTeacher'];
    }
    echo  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$url.'"> '.$value['name'].'</a><br>';
}
```

You left out how you build the `$url`, so I'm leaving that out as well.

Comment: Was about to post the same

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach, if you don't have `ORDER BY` clause in your `SQL` statement, is to define second array with keys - teacher names and items - students names for every teacher.

```
<?php

...
$output = array();
foreach($this->TeacherStudents as $key => $value){
    $teacher = $value['nameTeacher'];
    if (!array_key_exists($teacher, $output)) {
        $output[$teacher] = array();
    }   
    $output[$teacher][] = $value['name'];
}

foreach($output as $teacher => $students) {
    echo $teacher;
    foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'"> '.$value.'</a>  <span class="badge">';
    }   
}
...

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check below code and get your result.

```
$teacherWiseStdList = [];

foreach($this->TeacherStudents as $key => $value){
    $teacherWiseStdList[$value['nameTeacher']] = $value['name'];
}
```

Now you have to print the result like below way.

```
foreach(teacherWiseStdList as $teacherName => $studentName) {

  if (array_key_exists($teacherName, $teacherWiseStdList)) {
    echo $teacherName;
  } else {
      echo  '<a href="yourUrl"> '.$studentName.'</a>  <span class="badge">';
  }

}
```